# Jmeter: Passing boolean through command line

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where I want to control a Jmeter run (timed vs non-timed), so I have something like this in the plan.

```
<elementProp> name="SCHEDULER_VAR" elementType="Argument">
<boolProp> name="Argument.name">SCHEDULER_VAR</boolProp>
<boolProp> name="Argument.value">${__property(scheduler,,false)</boolProp>
<boolProp> name="Argument.metadata">=</boolProp>
</elementProp>
....
....
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">${SCHEDULER_VAR}</boolProp>
```

And I run jmeter from commandline using -Jscheduler=true (and set other parameters like duration, delay), but it always sets the ThreadGroup.scheduler to false resulting in infinite run, did my own tweakings, but without much success. I do see a getPropertyAsBoolean method in the jmeter AbstractTestElement, but not sure how to modify the XML to read the property as boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution, declare everything shown above as stringProp, that way we can override any parameters from command line, the below code works fine to create a timed run.

```
<elementProp> name="SCHEDULER_VAR" elementType="Argument">
<stringProp> name="Argument.name">SCHEDULER_VAR</stringProp>
<stringProp> name="Argument.value">${__property(scheduler,,false)</stringProp>
<stringProp> name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
</elementProp>
....
....
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">${SCHEDULER_VAR}</stringProp>
```

Then running jmeter with -Jscheduler=true with duration and delay does a timed run.